# How to integrate R Shiny app with Squarespace

Tags: r, shiny, squarespace

I am looking for ways to integrate a R Shiny app with Squarespace website, is it possible? e.g. can you use the Squarespace website structure with page links etc. and insert R Shiny components and logic with {{...}} or similar into the website itself? Any comments or suggestions appreciated.